# Django best practice for storing access keys

Tags: django, api, passwords

What's the best way to store API access keys that you need in your settings.py but that you don't want to commit into git?

Comment: You can find here: https://alicecampkin.medium.com/how-to-set-up-environment-variables-in-django-f3c4db78c55f a very detailed step-by-step guide that completes the missing steps in the chosen answer that a Django newbie like me doesn't know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use an environment file that stays on my computer and contains some variables linked to my environment.

In my Django settings.py (which is uploaded on github):

```
# MANDRILL API KEY
MANDRILL_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_MANDRILL_KEY')
```

On dev env, my .env file (which is excluded from my Git repo) contains:

```
DJANGO_MANDRILL_KEY=PuoSacohjjshE8-5y-0pdqs
```

This is a "pattern" proposed by Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

I suppose there is a simple way to setit without using Heroku though :)

To be honest, the primary goal to me is not security-related, but rather related to environment splitting. But it can help for both I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this in `settings.py`:

```
import json
if DEBUG:
    secret_file = '/path/to/development/config.json'
else:
    secret_file = '/path/to/production/config.json'
with open(secret_file) as f:
    SECRETS = json.loads(f)
secret = lambda n: str(SECRETS[n])
SECRET_KEY = secret('secret_key')
DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'] = secret('db_password')
```

and the JSON file:

```
{
    "db_password": "foo",
    "secret_key": "bar"
}
```

This way you can omit the production config from git or move it outside your repository.

Comment: I believe you should use json.load() instead of json.loads().